# Magento: which folder can I see my installed extensions?

Tags: magento

I have installed an extension in magento 1.5. Just wondering where it is on my server because i want to write an include file to it. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

typically in `[MagentoFolder]/app/code/community/[SomeCompanyName]/[SomePackageName]`

(otherwise, instead of "community" it could be "local").

For the location of Magento itself on your server, that depends on where you installed it! :)

Comment: do you know which table is used for log installed module

Comment: this is for installed extension.. what is the path to already created API's folder?

Answer (score 7):

The extension can either be in one of the following directory:

> [YourMagentoFolder]/app/code/local/

OR,

> [YourMagentoFolder]/app/code/community/

Here is the list of folder structure for all the files that can be in a Magento extension:- [Magento Folder Structure](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento-folder-structure)

Answer (score 0):

[magento folder]/app/code/community

Answer (score 0):

You can find your installed extensions in : 
your mail folder -> app/code/community

or

your mail folder -> app/code/local

Some of the extensions will be installed in local folder as well

[image]

You can find all in code folder