# Can't change the word on a button on Magento

Tags: magento, button, translation, jquery-cookie

I have installed a cookie bar extension via Magento Connect and it works just fine. I want now to change the text inside the  that says "Close".

I have written it in the translation files, cleaned my cache and nothing happened.

I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070858/magento-which-folder-can-i-see-my-installed-extensions?s=6%7C1.1259) and tried to find the button on the extension's files, but I can't find it.

Anyone has more ideas of how to solve this issue or point me to a solution? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I am using [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-cookie-consent.html)

Image of the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create translate you need to follow below steps :

Place your language package in /app/locale directory.

Now got to Admin c-panel > System > Configuration > General > Locale Options > Locale select you language pack from the Dropdown list.

[image]

you can also translate the words through Inline. Go to System > configuration > Developers > Translate Inline. After enabling this you can translate directly through UI

Comment: That almost helped me out! The cookie bar is the only thing that the system won't allow me to translate :/

Comment: for inline editor, just clear cache if you can't see changes after you reload